error response from daemon: rpc error: code = unvailable desc = connection error: desc= "transport": Error while dialing tcp
I have 3 containers in three different physical machines in the same LAN, I want them to communicate between them.
so I used docker swarm init --advertise-address @ip_Manager but I got an error :
Error response from daemon: must specify a listening address because the address to advertise is not recognized as a system address, and a system's IP address to use could not be uniquely identified.
I tried to only use docker swarm init so it worked and I got :
Swarm initialized: current node (mwlyh4wecukwf6duwv9cu99au) is now a manager. To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command: docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-55fkjzg3yo1z5rbud3nbyet0u0oh6xofjsbm2wn8cip3nclnot-a4sny3oenpu7ywh6h0f4de74g 192.168.65.3:2377 To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.
(The IP addr is different from the one i use in the LAN)
BUT when I try to add a worker it says : error response from daemon: rpc error: code = unvailable desc = connection error: desc= "transport": Error while dialing tcp 192.168.65.3:2377: connect: connection refused.
Knowing that there's a ping using the first address since the two machines are in the same LAN but there's no ping with the second address i get, what should i do ?
env : Windows10, Docker WSL2 subsystem Linux
